# Rust glium with spir-v not working at all

Tags: rust, opengl, spir-v, glium, winit

So my problem is that if I compile my glsl shaders with spirv (spirv-compiler rust lib) they dont work my guess is that the bindings and locations are either wrong in the shaders or in the rust code. My build.rs here:

```
use std::{fs::{read_dir, File, DirEntry}, io::Write};
use spirv_compiler::*;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let mut compiler = CompilerBuilder::new().with_include_dir("shaders/include").with_source_language(SourceLanguage::GLSL).with_target_spirv(SpirvVersion::V1_6).build().unwrap();
    for path in read_dir("shaders").unwrap() {
        let shader: DirEntry = path.unwrap();
        if shader.metadata().unwrap().is_file() {
            let compiled_data: Vec<u32> = compiler.compile_from_string(std::fs::read_to_string(shader.path()).unwrap().as_str(), get_shader_kind(shader.file_name().to_str().unwrap()).unwrap()).unwrap();
            let mut compiled_shader = File::create("shaderCache/".to_owned()+shader.file_name().as_os_str().to_str().unwrap()+".spv").unwrap();
            for &value in &compiled_data {
                compiled_shader.write_all(&value.to_ne_bytes()).unwrap();
            }
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}

fn get_shader_kind(file_name: &str) -> Option<ShaderKind> {
    match file_name.split('.').last().unwrap() {
        "vs" => Some(ShaderKind::Vertex),
        "fs" => Some(ShaderKind::Fragment),
        "gs" => Some(ShaderKind::Geometry),
        "tcs" => Some(ShaderKind::TessControl),
        "tes" => Some(ShaderKind::TessEvaluation),
        _ => { assert!(false, "The shader type is not supported or the filename is incorrect!"); None }
    }
}
```

window.rs (There is quite a lot of testing trash I am trying to get it working for long time):

```
use glium::{Surface, glutin::{self, surface::WindowSurface, context::Version}};
use std::{borrow::Cow, num::NonZeroU32, time::Instant};
use crate::graphics::types::{RenderVertex, Rotate};
use raw_window_handle::HasRawWindowHandle;
use crate::glium::glutin::prelude::*;
use glutin::display::GetGlDisplay;

implement_vertex!(RenderVertex, position, texture_coords);

#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct Material {
    color_override: [f32; 3]
}

implement_uniform_block!(Material, color_override);

fn get_position(vertices: &[RenderVertex]) -> [f32; 3] {
    let (sum_x, sum_y, sum_z) = vertices.iter().fold((0.0, 0.0, 0.0), |(acc_x, acc_y, acc_z), vertex| {
        (acc_x + vertex.position[0], acc_y + vertex.position[1], acc_z + vertex.position[2])
    });

    let num_vertices = vertices.len() as f32;

    [sum_x / num_vertices, sum_y / num_vertices, sum_z / num_vertices]
}

pub fn start() {
    let event_loop = winit::event_loop::EventLoopBuilder::new().build().expect("event loop building");
    let window_builder = winit::window::WindowBuilder::new().with_title("Glium SPIR-V example");
    let config_template_builder = glutin::config::ConfigTemplateBuilder::new();
    let display_builder = glutin_winit::DisplayBuilder::new().with_window_builder(Some(window_builder));
    
    let (window, gl_config) = display_builder
        .build(&event_loop, config_template_builder, |mut configs| {
            configs.next().unwrap()
        }).unwrap();
    let window = window.unwrap();

    let raw_window_handle = window.raw_window_handle();

    let context_attributes = glutin::context::ContextAttributesBuilder::new()
        .with_context_api(glutin::context::ContextApi::OpenGl(Some(Version::new(4, 6))))
        .build(Some(raw_window_handle));

    let not_current_gl_context = Some(unsafe {
        gl_config.display().create_context(&gl_config, &context_attributes).expect("failed to create context")
    });

    let (width, height): (u32, u32) = window.inner_size().into();
    let attrs = glutin::surface::SurfaceAttributesBuilder::<WindowSurface>::new().build(
        raw_window_handle,
        NonZeroU32::new(width).unwrap(),
        NonZeroU32::new(height).unwrap(),
    );
    
    let surface = unsafe { gl_config.display().create_window_surface(&gl_config, &attrs).unwrap() };
    let current_context = not_current_gl_context.unwrap().make_current(&surface).unwrap();
    let display = glium::Display::from_context_surface(current_context, surface).unwrap();

    let image = image::load(std::io::Cursor::new(std::fs::read(inner_path!("img/opengl_logo.png")).unwrap()), image::ImageFormat::Png).unwrap().to_rgba8();
    let image_dimensions = image.dimensions();
    let image = glium::texture::RawImage2d::from_raw_rgba_reversed(&image.into_raw(), image_dimensions);

    let texture = glium::texture::Texture2d::new(&display, image).unwrap();

    let image2 = image::load(std::io::Cursor::new(std::fs::read(inner_path!("img/pngegg.png")).unwrap()), image::ImageFormat::Png).unwrap().to_rgba8();
    let image2_dimensions = image2.dimensions();
    let image2 = glium::texture::RawImage2d::from_raw_rgba_reversed(&image2.into_raw(), image2_dimensions);

    let texture2 = glium::texture::Texture2d::new(&display, image2).unwrap();

    let mut shape = vec![
        RenderVertex { position: [-0.5, -0.5, 0.0], texture_coords: [0.0, 0.0], ..Default::default() },
        RenderVertex { position: [-0.5,  0.5, 0.0], texture_coords: [0.0, 1.0], ..Default::default() },
        RenderVertex { position: [ 0.5,  0.5, 0.0], texture_coords: [1.0, 1.0], ..Default::default() },
        RenderVertex { position: [ 0.5, -0.5, 0.0], texture_coords: [1.0, 0.0], ..Default::default() },
    ];
    let offset = [1.5, 0.0];
    let mut shape2 = vec![
        RenderVertex { position: [-0.5+offset[0], -0.5+offset[1], 0.0], texture_coords: [0.0, 0.0], ..Default::default() },
        RenderVertex { position: [-0.5+offset[0],  0.5+offset[1], 0.0], texture_coords: [0.0, 1.0], ..Default::default() },
        RenderVertex { position: [ 0.5+offset[0],  0.5+offset[1], 0.0], texture_coords: [1.0, 1.0], ..Default::default() },
        RenderVertex { position: [ 0.5+offset[0], -0.5+offset[1], 0.0], texture_coords: [1.0, 0.0], ..Default::default() },
    ];
    let offset2 = [0.0, 0.5];
    let mut shape3 = vec![
        RenderVertex { position: [-0.5+offset2[0], -0.5+offset2[1], 0.0], texture_coords: [0.0, 0.0], ..Default::default() },
        RenderVertex { position: [-0.5+offset2[0],  0.5+offset2[1], 0.0], texture_coords: [0.0, 1.0], ..Default::default() },
        RenderVertex { position: [ 0.5+offset2[0],  0.5+offset2[1], 0.0], texture_coords: [1.0, 1.0], ..Default::default() },
        RenderVertex { position: [ 0.5+offset2[0], -0.5+offset2[1], 0.0], texture_coords: [1.0, 0.0], ..Default::default() },
    ];
    const U32_INDICES: [u16; 6] = [0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 2];

    let indices = glium::IndexBuffer::new(&display, glium::index::PrimitiveType::TrianglesList, &U32_INDICES).unwrap();

    let material = glium::uniforms::UniformBuffer::new(&display, Material { color_override: [1f32, 1f32, 1f32] }).unwrap();
    let material2 = glium::uniforms::UniformBuffer::new(&display, Material { color_override: [1f32, 0f32, 0f32] }).unwrap();
    let material3 = glium::uniforms::UniformBuffer::new(&display, Material { color_override: [-2f32, 0f32, 0f32] }).unwrap();

    //const U32_NORMALS: [u16; 6] = [0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 2];
    //let normals = glium::VertexBuffer::new(&display, U32_NORMALS).unwrap();
    
    let vertex_shader_binary = std::fs::read(inner_path!("shaderCache/simple.vs.spv")).unwrap();
    let vertex_shader = glium::program::SpirvEntryPoint { binary: vertex_shader_binary.as_slice(), entry_point: "main" };
    let fragment_shader_binary = std::fs::read(inner_path!("shaderCache/simple.fs.spv")).unwrap();
    let fragment_shader = glium::program::SpirvEntryPoint { binary: fragment_shader_binary.as_slice(), entry_point: "main" };
    let spirv_program = glium::program::SpirvProgram::from_vs_and_fs(vertex_shader, fragment_shader);
    let program = glium::Program::new(&display, glium::program::ProgramCreationInput::SpirV(spirv_program)).unwrap();
    /*
    let vertex_shader = std::fs::read_to_string(inner_path!("shaders/simple.vs")).unwrap();
    let fragment_shader = std::fs::read_to_string(inner_path!("shaders/simple.fs")).unwrap();

    let program = glium::Program::from_source(&display, vertex_shader.as_str(), fragment_shader.as_str(), None).unwrap();
    */
    let mut last_frame_update = Instant::now();
    let _ = event_loop.run(move |event, control_flow| {
        match event {
            winit::event::Event::AboutToWait => window.request_redraw(),
            winit::event::Event::WindowEvent { event, .. } => match event {
                winit::event::WindowEvent::CloseRequested => control_flow.exit(),
                winit::event::WindowEvent::Resized(window_size) => { display.resize(window_size.into()); },
                winit::event::WindowEvent::RedrawRequested => {
                    let rotation = 0.0000005 * last_frame_update.elapsed().as_micros() as f32;
                    last_frame_update = Instant::now();

                    shape.rotate([0.0, rotation, 0.0].into(), get_position(&shape).into());
                    shape2.rotate([0.0, rotation, 0.0].into(), [0.0, 0.0, 0.0].into());
                    shape3.rotate([rotation, 0.0, 0.0].into(), get_position(&shape3).into());

                    static BINDINGS: glium::vertex::VertexFormat = &[
                        (
                            Cow::Borrowed("position"), 0, 0,
                            glium::vertex::AttributeType::F32F32F32, false
                        ),
                        (
                            Cow::Borrowed("texture_coords"), 3 * ::std::mem::size_of::<f32>(), 1,
                            glium::vertex::AttributeType::F32F32, false
                        ),
                    ];
                    let vertex_buffer = unsafe {
                        glium::VertexBuffer::new_raw(&display, &shape,
                        BINDINGS, 5 * ::std::mem::size_of::<f32>()).unwrap()
                    };
                    let vertex_buffer2 = unsafe {
                        glium::VertexBuffer::new_raw(&display, &shape2,
                        BINDINGS, 5 * ::std::mem::size_of::<f32>()).unwrap()
                    };
                    let vertex_buffer3 = unsafe {
                        glium::VertexBuffer::new_raw(&display, &shape3,
                        BINDINGS, 5 * ::std::mem::size_of::<f32>()).unwrap()
                    };

                    let uniforms = uniform! {
                        texture_2d: &texture,
                        Material: &material
                    };

                    let uniforms_2 = uniform! {
                        texture_2d: &texture,
                        Material: &material2
                    };

                    let uniforms_3 = uniform! {
                        texture_2d: &texture2,
                        Material: &material3
                    };

                    let mut frame = display.draw();

                    let params = glium::DrawParameters {
                        depth: glium::Depth {
                            test: glium::draw_parameters::DepthTest::IfLess,
                            write: true,
                            .. Default::default()
                        },
                        blend: glium::draw_parameters::Blend::alpha_blending(),
                        .. Default::default()
                    };

                    frame.clear_color_and_depth((0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0), 1.0);
                    let _ = frame.draw(&vertex_buffer, &indices, &program, &uniforms, &params);
                    let _ = frame.draw(&vertex_buffer2, &indices, &program, &uniforms_2, &params);
                    let _ = frame.draw(&vertex_buffer3, &indices, &program, &uniforms_3, &params);
                    frame.finish().unwrap();

                    glium::assert_no_gl_error!(display);
                },
                _ => ()
            }
            _ => ()
        }
    });
}
```

simple.vs (vertex shader):

```
#version 460

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 texture_coords;
//layout(location = 2) in vec3 normal;

layout(location = 2) out vec2 vertex_texture_coords;
/*layout(location = 1) out vec3 v_normal;

layout(set = 0, binding = 1) uniform Camera {
    mat4 perspective;
    vec3 view;
} camera;*/

void main() {
    vertex_texture_coords = texture_coords;

    /*/vec3 finalPosition = camera.view * position;

    gl_Position = camera.perspective * vec4(finalPosition, 1.0);/*/
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

simple.fs (fragment shader):

```
#version 460

layout(binding = 0) uniform sampler2D texture_2d;
layout(binding = 1) uniform Material {
    vec3 color_override;
};

layout(location = 2) in vec2 vertex_texture_coords;
layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;

void main() {
    vec4 texture_color = texture(texture_2d, vertex_texture_coords);

    if (color_override.r < 0.0) {
        color = vec4(texture_color.rgb * texture_color.a, texture_color.a);
    } else {
        color = vec4(color_override * texture_color.a, texture_color.a);
    }
}
```

This is not even near the code I will be using later by I am strugling with getting the stirv working correctly so thats why the code is such mess currently.

I have tried changing the locations in the shaders and even tried glsl to hlsl and than to spirv. It works when directly putting the shaders to glium without compiling it with spirv.